# is there a ${SSH_CONNECTION%% *} equivalent in Telnet?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, telnet

So on RedHat Linux...

I have a rather unique application where I need to determine what address a telnet connection is occurring on. The application will use a loopback address to Telnet to it's self, and will be fed different information based on what loopback address it connects to.

For SSH we were using ${SSH_CONNECTION%% *}. However I cannot find a Telnet equivalent. If there is not one we will likely just run a second SSH Daemon. However the powers that be would rather run telnet.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There's almost certainly a better way to determine what you need than `ssh/telnet localhost`. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: We have 200 devices that our configuration management software cannot connect to so instead we trick the software into connecting to its own server running a function "show running configuration" and then cat the desired configuration to it. We use the address the software connects on to determine what configuration to feed it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well that command is just echoing out the environment varibale for ssh_connection

You can telnet in and do an env and look for your IP and see if it is there:

or you can

```
who grep $(whoami)|awk '{print $NF}'
```

run something like above